# Furman power conditioner - can I use with a power bar to expand my outputs?

Tags: setup, power, sound-quality

I've been running my studio setup of about 15 - 16 pieces of audio gear (computer, monitors, mixer, etc) using a couple of surge protected power bars. I decided it would be a good idea to get a power conditioner, and settled on a Furman PL-8C. Since this power conditioner only has 9 outlets on it, I can't plug all my gear into it. Is it safe to plug a power bar into one of the 9 outlets to expand my outputs?

**EDIT**
In addition, would using a power bar eliminate some of the benefits of having a power conditioner in the first place? I'm thinking I would no longer have any benefit from the isolated banks designed to reduce inter-component interference, at least for the specific components plugged into the power bar.

Comment: It's safe as long as you don't try to draw too much current, which the furman probably won't let you do. If you are using detachable power cords, make sure they are thick as you can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine plugging your power bar into the furman (i do the same thing) as long as you don't pull too much current.

The pl-8c has a 15amp 'breaker' on it, so don't exceed that.

I don't think using your power bar would nullify the benefits of the furman 'cleans' in the incoming ac current then delivers it to it's outputs, which your power bar plugs into. Now, would your power bar 'dirty' up that current again is anyone's question...