# Expanding Furman AC 210 E with power strip?

Tags: home-studio, power

To some extent this is a duplicate of [this post](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/37036/furman-power-conditioner-can-i-use-with-a-power-bar-to-expand-my-outputs), but I'm not sure of what that poster meant with 'power bar' exactly...

I'm setting up a home recording studio and plan on getting a Furman PL-8 CE with 10 outlets to condition the power and provide surge protection.

I already have a Furman AC 210 E, which has only two outlets.  It has been suggested to me that I could use [this product](https://www.thomann.de/intl/the_t.racks_power_8.htm) to give myself more outlets...basically just plugging multiple outlets into one of the AC 210's outlets.

I feel certain I've read somewhere that this is a bad idea, but I can't find that information now.  Does anyone have any technical reason why this is either a good or a bad idea?  In the original post above, I believe it says that it will probably work, but that it might 'dirty' the power again.  There will be some delicate equipment plugged into it, and the whole point is to take care of it, so I'm not keen to take chances, but I'm just curious...

Comment: This really is a duplicate of [Furman power conditioner - can I use with a power bar to expand my outputs?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/37036/furman-power-conditioner-can-i-use-with-a-power-bar-to-expand-my-outputs) Any additional information is probably more suited to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: OK; thanks, I'll post it there.